# Image on click code is too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onclick

I made this code so that when you click one of the nine images, you get another one (I made images with text on Photoshop). My code works fine but it is just really long. Does anyone know how to make it shorter?

Javascript:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { /*Altijd aanroepen per script*/


   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwo.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwohover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwo.png";
       }
     })

   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange2', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdone.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdonehover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdone.png";
       }
     })

   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange3', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdthree.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdthreehover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange3").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdthree.png";
       }
     })

   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange4', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfour.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfourhover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange4").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfour.png";
       }
     })

   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange5', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfive.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfivehover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange5").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdfive.png";
       }
     })
   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange6', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdsix.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdsixhover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange6").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdsix.png";
       }
     })
   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange7', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdseven.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdsevenhover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange7").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdseven.png";
       }
     })
   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange8', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdeight.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdeighthover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange8").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdeight.png";
       }
     })
   $(document)
     .on('click', '#imgClickAndChange9', function changeImage() {

       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdnine.png") {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdninehover.png";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange9").src = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdnine.png";
       }
     })



 });
CSS:
```

```css
#pictures {
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  color: rgb(204, 55, 77);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.onethird {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pictures">
  <img src="img/thirdtwo.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdone.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange2" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdthree.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange3" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdfour.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange4" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdfive.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange5" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdsix.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange6" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdseven.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange7" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdeight.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange8" onclick="changeImage()"></img>
  <img src="img/thirdnine.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange9" onclick="changeImage()"></img>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use switch statments instead

Comment: Just another one got a "my code is too long" itch...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick` attributes, as you don't need them (and it's [not really good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice?lq=1) to use them). `click` event handlers are set in yur JS code.

This should do the job for your HTML example:

```
$('.onethird').click(function(e){
    var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
    var new_src = old_src.indexOf('hover') > -1 ? old_src.replace('hover', '') : old_src.split(".")[0] + 'hover.png';
    $(this).attr('src', new_src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two things.  First put both your urls on each of your elements.

```
<img src="img/thirdtwo.png" class="onethird" id="imgClickAndChange1" data-src="img/thirdtwo.png" data-srchover="img/thirdtwohover.png"></img>
```

Then when they all follow that pattern you could do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.onethird', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is('.hoverDisplayed')) {
        //is hover, so we need to revert it
        $this.attr('src', $this.data('src');
    } else {
        //is not hover, so make it hover
        $this.attr('src', $this.data('srchover');
    }

    //toggle the class to reflect what it should be next time
    $this.toggleClass('hoverDisplayed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hoverFile(filename){
    if (filename.indexOf('hover') != -1){
        // remove hover
        console.log('remove');
        var updatedFilename = filename.replace('hover','');
    }
    else {
        // add hover
        console.log('add');
        var extension = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        var originalFilename = filename.substr( 0, filename.indexOf( "." ) );
        var updatedFilename = originalFilename + 'hover.' + extension;
    }
    return updatedFilename;
}

$(document).ready(function() { /*Altijd aanroepen per script*/
    $('.onethird').click(function() {
        console.log('before: ' + this.src);
        this.src = hoverFile(this.src);
        console.log('after:' + this.src);
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="pictures">
    <img src="img/thirdtwo.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdone.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdthree.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdfour.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdfive.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdsix.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdseven.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdeight.png" class="onethird"></img>
    <img src="img/thirdnine.png" class="onethird"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).on('click', '.onethird', function changeImage() {
  var imagePath = document.getElementsByClassName("onethird")[0].src;
if (imagePath  == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwo.png") {
       imagePath = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwohover.png";
}
else if ( imagePath  == "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwo.png") {
       imagePath  = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwohover.png";
}
.
.
.
.

else{
      imagePath  = "http://127.0.0.1:50150/img/thirdtwo.png";
}

});
```

Comment: A little bit of elaboration might help OP understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunarely I already started working on a solution for you before I saw others posted, oh well! Here is what I wrote up for you.

I went with one general `click` event listener for a generic class you can apply to all your images you want to swap when clicked. When an image is clicked, it will swap images with names you defined using the `data-` attribute available on `HTML` elements. I am using the jQuery `.attr()` function because I do not know which jQuery version you're using and `.data()` isn't available for earlier versions of jQuery. Please let me know if this works out for you, or if I need to make adjustments. Code is posted below, cheers!

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalImages = 10;
  var basePath = '/img/';
  var hoverClass = 'is-hover';
  var clickImageSelector = '.imgClickAndChange';

  function changeImage() {
      var $img          = $(this);
      var hoverImg  = $img.attr('data-hover-img');
      var staticImg = $img.attr('data-static-img');

      if ($img.hasClass(hoverClass)) {
          // Set Image SRC to staticImg if using hoverImg
          // (determined by existance of hoverClass)
          $img.attr('src', basePath + staticImg);
          $img.removeClass(hoverClass);
      }
      else {
          // Set Image SRC to hoverImg if using staticImg
          // (determined by existance of hoverClass)
          $img.attr('src', basePath + hoverImg);
          $img.addClass(hoverClass);
      }
  }

  $(document).on('click', clickImageSelector, changeImage);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="pictures">
  <img src="img/thirdone.png" class="imgClickAndChange onethird" data-static-img='thirdone.png' data-hover-img='thirdonehover.png' />
  <img src="img/thirdtwo.png" class="imgClickAndChange onethird" data-static-img='thirdtwo.png' data-hover-img='thirdtwohover.png' />
  <img src="img/thirdthree.png" class="imgClickAndChange onethird" data-static-img='thirdthree.png' data-hover-img='thirdthreehover.png' />
  <img src="img/thirdfour.png" class="imgClickAndChange onethird" data-static-img='thirdfour.png' data-hover-img='thirdfourhover.png' />
  ...
  <img src="img/thirdnine.png" class="imgClickAndChange onethird" data-static-img='thirdnine.png' data-hover-img='thirdninehover.png' />
</div>
```